# Why doesn't my eye diagram code in matlab work?

Tags: matlab, signals, diagram

I have java code that will turn a polynomial into a binary sequence and then turns it into PAM4 data. The PAM4 data is stored in a csv file and im trying to import it and then plot an eye diagram from it in matlab. My code doesn't plot the diagram and i want to know why.

Here is my code

```
data = readmatrix('PAM4.csv', 'NumHeaderLines', 1);

time = data(:, 1);
voltage = data(:, 2);

UI = 10; 
samplesPerBit = size(data, 1);

numBits = size(data, 1);

numSymbols = floor(samplesPerBit / UI);

cutWaveform = zeros(numBits, numSymbols);

for i = 1:numBits
    for j = 1:numSymbols
        startIndex = 1 + (j - 1) * UI;
        endIndex = startIndex + UI - 1;
        cutWaveform(i, j) = mean(voltage(startIndex:endIndex));
    end
end

figure;
hold on;
for i = 1:numBits
    plot(cutWaveform(i, :), 'b');
end

title('Eye Diagram');
xlabel('Symbol Index');
ylabel('Amplitude');
grid on;
```

When i run this code, it opens up a plot but it only has a straight line. I want to create a clear eye diagram. Is my dataset too small?

Comment: Your question is related to Java coding only indirectly, and so the [tag:java] tag is not necessary and possibly even confusing, and so I have removed it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, please read [ask] and [minimal-reproducible-exampl](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Right now, no one can reproduce your problem nor really understand what the problem is.